# Using Xcode with TFS 2015 on-premises

Tags: ios, xcode, git, visual-studio, tfs

Is there any way to check in code from Xcode to TFS 2015 on-premises installation? Even if TFS is just acting as a go between for Xcode and Git? The main thing we'd like to be able to do is for iOS code to be checked in to TFS with changesets recorded, and work items/bugs available.

Any suggestions? We are not looking to move to VS Team Services / VS Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options.

1. The best option is to [create a new TFS Team Project with Git for source control. Or you can add a Git repo so an existing Team Project.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/create-new-repo) This is a standard Git repo, but hosted in TFS. It works just like any other hosted Git repo. Clone the repo and off you go.
2. If you cannot use Git inside TFS and you must use TFVC then you can use [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com/). This is effectively a bridge between a local git repo and a centralized TFS TFVC repo. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ethomson/2012/08/28/team-foundation-server-and-xcode-projects-with-git-tf/) should get you started

Answer (score 1):

Both VSTS and TFS 2015 include full support for Git-based source control projects. You can follow MSDN article [Share your code in Git using Xcode](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode) to [push](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/git/tutorial/pushing) your project to TFS.

After pushing your project to TFS, you'll have full history and work item available:

[image]

[image]